# Definition a bit technical for a general audience

Tags: cryptic-clues

... which is a shame because I love grids with 15-letter words but find it hard to fill them.
No doubt someone here will have the erudition to solve it ;)

`Variables are hidden in this unconventionally pretty Iowa hovel (5, 4, 6)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is

> PILOT WAVE THEORY

a reference to

> David Bohm's (and, I add at OP's insistence, Louis de Broglie's) unorthodox interpretation of quantum mechanics.

Structure of the clue:

> the definition is "Variables are hidden in this"; "unconventionally" is an anagram indicator and "pretty Iowa hovel" its fodder.

Comment: Not sure I can accept this answer until you also credit de Broglie ;)

Comment: OK, I have done.